# Model state errors do not persist across redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have these models:

```
public class TicketViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    //...
}

public class UserProfileViewModel
{
    //Various properties
    public TicketViewModel Ticket { get; set; }
}
```

I have a controller action that takes a ticket for submission. The `Index` action returns a `UserProfileViewModel` object to a page (models are split up amongst partial views, pagination is done on the front-end).  When I redirect to the Index action, the ModelState is not preserved:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitTicket(TicketViewModel model)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid || !model.BooleanProperty)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Invalid Ticket", "Your ticket was filled out incorrectly.");
        var userViewModel = GenerateUserViewModel();
        userViewModel.Ticket = model;
        TempData["UserProfile"] = userViewModel;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
   //...
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = (TempData["UserProfile"] as UserProfileViewModel) ?? GenerateUserViewModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

I know that the model properties are being preserved correctly, but none of the errors are appearing in the view's validation sections.  When extracting the ticket out to its own view, it works just fine.

Comment: model errors always lost on redirect you cannot preserve it.....

Comment: Is there any way to get them back?

Comment: i think below answer will solve your problem if need more help then plz comment....

Answer (score 0):

Binding errors (and errors you add with the `AddModelError()` method) are added to `Errors` property of `ModelState`, not to the model itself.  If you want to pass along some errors to another view, one way would be to add the message to `TempData` and then extract them in the `Index()` method to display in the view.

Its a bit old, but [this blog](http://www.gxclarke.org/2010/05/consumption-of-data-in-mvc2-views.html) gives a good explanation

But if the model has errors, why not return the view (rather than redirecting to another view)so the the user can correct them?

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid())
{
  return View(model);
}
// redirect if valid
```

PS. You are using `AddModelError("Invalid Ticket", ...` which would add the error message to a property named `Invalid Ticket`, which does not exist (the first parameter is the name of the property to assign the error to).

Answer (score 0):

**Modelstate lost it's value on redirect...so this will solve your problem :**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitTicket(TicketViewModel model)
{
var errormessage="";
if(!ModelState.IsValid || !model.BooleanProperty)
{
    //ModelState.AddModelError("Invalid Ticket", "Your ticket was filled out incorrectly.");
    errormessage = "Your ticket was filled out incorrectly.";
    var userViewModel = GenerateUserViewModel();
    userViewModel.Ticket = model;
    TempData["UserProfile"] = userViewModel;
    return RedirectToAction("Index",new{ msg = errormessage });
}
}

public ActionResult Index(string msg)
{
var model = (TempData["UserProfile"] as UserProfileViewModel) ?? GenerateUserViewModel();
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg)){
ModelState.AddModelError("Invalid Ticket", msg);
}
return View(model);
}
```

---------------OR---------------

**You can also use TempData because it persists its value on one redirect as shown :**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitTicket(TicketViewModel model)
{
if(!ModelState.IsValid || !model.BooleanProperty)
{
    //ModelState.AddModelError("Invalid Ticket", "Your ticket was filled out incorrectly.");
    TempData["InvalidTicket"]="Your ticket was filled out incorrectly.";
    var userViewModel = GenerateUserViewModel();
    userViewModel.Ticket = model;
    TempData["UserProfile"] = userViewModel;
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
var model = (TempData["UserProfile"] as UserProfileViewModel) ?? GenerateUserViewModel();
ModelState.AddModelError("Invalid Ticket", TempData["InvalidTicket"].ToString());
return View(model);
}
```